# Usage of the [research] tag

Tags: discussion

Looking at the [questions tagged with [research]](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), I am not sure what this is supposed to be. Some people seem to be using it for "I am trying to find something" whereas some people are using it to ask about the institutions of economics research. To be clear, the question is not a binary, the above are just examples.

Can we come to a consensus and edit the usage guidance accordingly?

Please submit what you recon is the best usage guidance for this tag.

---

P.s. We should also strike the tag from older questions where it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The research tag should be used to ask about the institutions of research.

The first definition is extremely broad, and not useful. I would argue that even asking a question here forms a type of research.

Tags where the first definition was used should be removed.

Comment: To be clear, the question is not a binary, the above are just examples. (Will edit this into the question.) There are several other uses for the tag, e.g., "I am writing a research paper and..."

Comment: I understand, but the first use of the question should be eliminated. There's no use I can think of for having such a broad tag.